# Recompile Apache on Ubuntu Hardy

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

Does anyone have any idea how to do this. I installed build-essentials already but am totally lost. I am a linux compile newbie!

I need to change apache to Worker MPM mode, limited to a single process for a messaging app I am working on.

Thanks in advance

Rich

Comment: Why are you using hardy, out of interest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to recompile it.  Just install apache2-mpm-worker

`sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker`

And it'll install the correct binaries for you.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that, I will try it tomorrow. Many thanks Tom